# mySQL Conditional Syntax Issue

Tags: mysql

Essentially I would like to determine a value based on a conditional and then use that value inside a different conditional all in the same select statement.

**Example:**

```
IF(IF (`date1` IS NOT NULL AND `date1 ` <> 0), 
`date1`, `date2` AS processdate) = curdate(), "ready", "not ready" AS action_status
```

To determine `processdate` I am saying check the field `date1` has a date, if so use it, otherwise use `date2` as `processdate`.

Once `processdate` is determined, compare it to todays date, if they are equal set `action_status` = "ready", otherwise "not ready".

I believe the syntax is incorrect, what is the correct format for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

`AS` can only apply to an entire expression for a return value of the select; you can't embed it in an expression.  And each IF needs parentheses around its three arguments.  So:

```
IF(
    curdate() =
        IF(
            `date1` IS NOT NULL AND `date1 ` <> 0, 
            `date1`,
            `date2`
        ),
    "ready",
    "not ready"
) AS action_status
```

(I changed `... = curdate()` to be `curdate() = ...` just because I think it's more readable that way; either would work.)